# Get pdo table information from query with multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$lister_query = "
  SELECT * FROM (SELECT 
    lister1_password lister_password,
    lister1_status   lister_status,
    lister1_email    lister_email
  FROM lister1
  UNION
  SELECT 
    lister2_password lister_password,
    lister2_status   lister_status,
    lister2_email    lister_email
  FROM lister2
  UNION
  SELECT 
    lister3_password lister_password,
    lister3_status   lister_status,
    lister3_email    lister_email
  FROM lister3) AS lister
  WHERE lister.lister_password = ? AND lister.lister_email = ?
"; 

$lister_prepare = $database_listers -> prepare($lister_query);
$lister_prepare                     -> execute($_EXECUTE);

$_LISTER_COUNT = $lister_prepare -> rowCount();

if ($_LISTER_COUNT === 1) {
  $_LISTER = $lister_prepare -> fetch();

  $lister_status = $_LISTER['lister_status'];
  $lister_key    = $_LISTER['lister_key'];
}
```

How can I find the table that the email & password set was found. I need to know if it was lister1, lister2 or lister3 that was found. Is this possible?

**SOLUTION (currently not working)**

```
$lister_query = "
      SELECT * FROM (SELECT 
        lister1_password lister_password,
        lister1_status   lister_status,
        lister1_email    lister_email,
        'test1' test
      FROM lister1
      UNION
      SELECT
        lister2_password lister_password,
        lister2_status   lister_status,
        lister2_email    lister_email,
        'test2' test
      FROM lister2
      UNION
      SELECT
        lister3_password lister_password,
        lister3_status   lister_status,
        lister3_email    lister_email,
        'test3' test
      FROM lister3) AS lister
      WHERE lister.lister_password = ? AND lister.lister_email = ?
    "; 

    $lister_prepare = $database_listers -> prepare($lister_query);
    $lister_prepare                     -> execute($_EXECUTE);

    $_LISTER_COUNT = $lister_prepare -> rowCount();

    if ($_LISTER_COUNT === 1) {
      $_LISTER = $lister_prepare -> fetch();

     echo $_LISTER['test'];

      $lister_status = $_LISTER['lister_status'];
      $lister_key    = $_LISTER['lister_key'];
    }
```

I added the solutions talked about. It is not echoing out the test variable and non of the other fetched variables are working now from before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could add another column to each `UNION SELECT` where you define the table

```
$lister_query = "
  SELECT * FROM (SELECT 
    lister1_password lister_password,
    lister1_status   lister_status,
    lister1_email    lister_email,
    'lister1'        lister_table  // define lister_table
  FROM lister1
  UNION
  SELECT 
    lister2_password lister_password,
    lister2_status   lister_status,
    lister2_email    lister_email,
    'lister2'        lister_table  // define lister_table
  FROM lister2
  UNION
  SELECT 
    lister3_password lister_password,
    lister3_status   lister_status,
    lister3_email    lister_email,
    'lister3'        lister_table  // define lister_table
  FROM lister3) AS lister
  WHERE lister.lister_password = ? AND lister.lister_email = ?
"; 

...
[rest of your code]
...

if ($_LISTER_COUNT === 1) {
  $_LISTER = $lister_prepare -> fetch();

  $lister_table = $_LISTER['lister_table']; // the table it came from
  $lister_status = $_LISTER['lister_status'];
  $lister_key    = $_LISTER['lister_key'];
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate on `this did not work`? I just realized that I had `$lister_status = $_LISTER['lister_table']` instead of `$lister_table = $_LISTER['lister_table']`. Do you get anything in `$_LISTER['lister_table']`?

Comment: I added the additional column and echoed out the table_name from the fetched data. Now, no data is fetched at all.

Comment: If no data is fetched at all, then your query is most likely failing. did you remove my comments `// define lister_table`? Did you put a comma `,` after `lister_email` but before `'lister1`? Did you try your query directly in mysql to make sure it works?

Comment: Yes, I double checked everything. I will post my altered version

Comment: When I echo out the COUNT, it is showing 3 when it should only show 1.

Comment: OK it worked. Unfortunately I duplicated the tables and also the data. So I had 3 of results.

Comment: If `$_LISTER_COUNT === 3`, then you need to look at why 3 rows are returned. Do you have the same rows/values in each table? If so, by adding your `'test1' test` you will now get 3 distinct rows, where before you would only have 1 row as the other 2 would be removed by `UNION` as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
$lister_query = "
  SELECT * FROM (SELECT 
    lister1_password lister_password,
    lister1_status   lister_status,
    lister1_email    lister_email,
    'lister1' as table_name
  FROM lister1
  UNION
  SELECT 
    lister2_password lister_password,
    lister2_status   lister_status,
    lister2_email    lister_email,
    'lister2' as table_name
  FROM lister2
  UNION
  SELECT 
    lister3_password lister_password,
    lister3_status   lister_status,
    lister3_email    lister_email,
    'lister3' as table_name
  FROM lister3) AS lister
  WHERE lister.lister_password = ? AND lister.lister_email = ?
";
```